# Adding Values to a Byte Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm starting with the two values below:

```
finalString = "38,05,e1,5f,aa,5f,aa,d0";
string[] holder = finalString.Split(',');
```

I'm looping thru holder like so:

```
foreach (string item in holder)
{
  //concatenate 0x and add the value to a byte array
}
```

On each iteration I would like to concatenate a 0x to make it a hex value and add it to a byte array.

This is what I want the byte array to be like when I finish the loop:

```
byte[] c = new byte[]{0x38,0x05,0xe1,0x5f,0xaa,0x5f,0xaa,0xd0};
```

So far all my attempts have not been successful. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to concatenate the prefix "0x". This prefix is used by the C# compiler when parsing literals, but `byte.Parse` doesn't use it

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[holder.Length];
int i = 0;
foreach (string item in holder)
{
    myByteArray[i++] = byte.Parse(item, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as a one-liner:

```
var c = holder.Select(s => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToArray();
```

`c` is now a byte array with the data you need.

Comment: Cool idea, but edit your post so that the byte is parsed in hex mode.

Comment: s represents a value in the hexadecimal format. It may contain letters form A to F. byte.Parse needs a second argument specifying format.

Answer (score 1):

just create a new byte array which is the size of both arrays put together. Then insert one, and insert the second into the new buffer.  array sizes in .net are non-mutable

another approach would be to use something like List, and then just loop through each array and add it

```
var buffer = new List<byte>();
foreach(var b in firstArray) buffer.Add(b);
foreach(var b2 in secondArray) buffer.Add(b2);

byte[] newArray = buffer.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will generate the list of byte values based on the comma separated hex values you have:

```
     string hex_numbers = "38,05,e1,5f,aa,5f,aa,d0";
     string[] hex_values = hex_numbers.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     byte[] byte_array = new byte[hex_values.Length];
     for(int i = 0; i < hex_values.Length; i++)
     {
        byte_array[i] = byte.Parse(hex_values[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
     }
```